# assertequal for method of object type

Tags: java, testing, junit, assert

I am trying to make a test method using Junit test case for `GetTeextBook()` in `Course` class.  Notice that `GetTextBook()` is type of `Textbook` object but I always get a failure when I run the `CourseTestCase1` class in the method `testGetTextBook()`.

any suggestion?

**CourseTestCase1**

```
public class CourseTestCase1 {

  private Course course=new Course(101, "Software Engineering");

  @Test
  public void testGetTextBook() {
    Textbook testbook=new Textbook(700, "Data Base System", "Ramez ELmasri",2011);
    assertEquals(testbook,course.getTextbook());
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetCourseCode() {
    assertEquals(101,course.getCourseCode());
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetName() {
    assertEquals("Software Engineering",course.getName());
  }

  @Test
  public void testToString() {
    testGetCourseCode();
    testGetName();
  }
}
```

**Course**

```
public class Course {

  private int courseCode;
  private String courseName;
  private Textbook textbook;

  private Semester semestr;

  public Course() {
    this.courseCode = 0;
    this.courseName = null;

    this.semestr = null;
    this.textbook = null;
  }

  public Course(int courseCode, String courseName) {
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
    this.courseName = courseName;

    semestr = null;
    textbook = null;
  }

  public Textbook getTextbook() {
    return textbook;
  }
}
```

**Textbook**

```
public class Textbook {
  private int isbn;
  private String title, authors;
  private int publicationYear;

  private TextbookCopy tbcopy;

  public Textbook() {
    isbn = 0;
    title = null;
    authors = null;
    publicationYear = 0;
  }

  public Textbook(int isbn, String title, String authors, int publicationYear) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = authors;
    this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
  }

  public Textbook(int isbn, String title, String authors, int publicationYear,
                  String publisher, String distributor, double purchasePrice) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = authors;
    this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public int getPublicationYear() {
    return publicationYear;
  }

  public String getAuthors() {
    return authors;
  }

  public Textbook getBook() {
    return this;
  }

  public int getISBN() {
    return isbn;
  }

  public String getCopy() {
    return Integer.toString(tbcopy.numbersOfCopy);
  }

  public void USwoltextbook(int isbn) {
  }

  public void assignNewBook() {
  }

  public Textbook createNewTextBook(String info) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is Textbook object? Does it have its equals() method defined?

Comment: You never set Course.textbook it is always null.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev updated

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly define `Textbook.equals()` method. Default implementation just checks whether it's the same object. In your case it would be reasonable to check whether field contents is the same. If you are using IDE, there should be a button to generate such `equals()` method automatically (for example, in Eclipse: Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()).

Comment: You should also override `int hashCode()` if you override `boolean equals(Object)` for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The assertEquals method from Junit is written as follows:

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (expected != null && expected.equals(actual)) {
        return;
    }
    failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
}
```

and

```
static public void assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    assertEquals(null, expected, actual);
}
```

So as you can see it uses the equals method of the expected object to make the comparison, therefore to make it work properly you should override `equals`method.